# How to perform order by limit 1 inside a jsonb cell in postgres?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table in postgres

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id serial primary key,
    col_1 jsonb,

    ....
```

Inside `col_1`, I have a structure like this

```
[{"date": "2018-10-13", "val_1": 90.8, "val_2": 87.9},
 {"date": "2018-10-03", "val_1": 90.2, "val_2": 83.2},
 {"date": "2018-10-11", "val_1": 92.8, "val_2": 88.9},
 ...
]
```

Now I need to query something like this

```
SELECT "latest date from the jsonb" WHERE id = {some_id};
```

In order to do that, I should be able to order/sort the array in `col_1` by date in descending order (convert the date string first using the `to_date` function) then get the first element of that sorted array. How can I do this in postgres?

Comment: `select tbl.id, max(tbl.date_col) from (select id, to_date(jsonb_array_elements_text(col_1)::jsonb->>'date', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date_col from my_table) tbl group by tbl.id having tbl.id = {some_id};` should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud unnest the json array using the function [`jsonb_array_elements():`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
select (jsonb_array_elements(col_1)->>'date')::date as date
from my_table
where id = 1
order by date desc
limit 1

    date    
------------
 2018-10-13
(1 row)
```